# Where with a greater than option in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a filter function and if i select the number 3 it should show me also the tests with the number 1 and 2

so i need a multiple "where" who shows me all tests with the number who are less than 3

i tried something like this:

```
$tests = DB::table('tests')->orderBy('name', 'asc')-where('number', < 3)->get();
```

it shows me that is not possible but is there a right laravel syntax to do something like this?

i cant find anything about it

because i always use where('number', 1) so like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is not correct, so change it to:

```
where('number', '<=', 3)  // '<=' for 1,2,3. If you want only 1,2 try '<'
```

and there is an issue here:

`-where`

change it to:

`->where`

and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use less than mark as a string ('<') as a 2nd param and value as a 3rd param. For example:

```
$tests = DB::table('tests')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->where('number', '<', 3)->get();
```

If you use equal to ('=') mark you can use value as a 2nd param.

Answer (score 0):

You can get detail knowledge from below link with multiple examples
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses

```
$selected_number = '3';

$tests = DB::table('tests')->where('number', '<=', $selected_number)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```